# how to define anonymous data-structure in golang

Tags: templates, go

I am new to golang and you may find my question very silly. But still I have tried my leave best to find solution for my problem but no luck.

I need to keep mapping in below data structure which I want to use later in generating page from template. If I need to define below data structure in Python or Perl then I can do it easily do this.

Below is sample code for python.

```
{
    'abc' : {
        '1' : ['A', 'B', 'C']
    }
    'def' : {
        '1': {
            'key1':'val1',
            'key2':'val2',
            .....
            ...
            },
        '2':{
            'key1':'val1',
            'key2':'val2',
            .....
            ...
            },
        ....
        ....
    }
}
```

Is there any easy way to achieve the same in golang? I understand that by uses of **make(map[string]map[string]string)** or
**make(map[string]interface{})** . But still this seems me quite unreadable.

**Update 1:**
Just clicked the idea that I can define the same structure in JSON format as well. But still is there any other way directly at language level?

Comment: Why not define a proper type that satisfies the structure you need?

Comment: i am talking about readability here. The python / Perl code seems more readable.

Comment: What do you consider "unreadable"? You haven't shown an example of what didn't work for you in Go. Go is statically typed, so you're going to have type definitions _somewhere_ in the code.

Answer (score 2):

It is probably easier to define a type (either at the package level or within the function), but you can define literal structs inline (arrays of these are usually seen in table-driven tests).

```
blah := struct{
    s string
    f int
}{"blah",12}
```

These can be nested arbitrarily, but it gets to be harder to read.